# Why the phonon modes may not be horizontal at the brillouin zone boundary?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, phonons

In the book *Principles of the Theory of Solids* by Ziman, it says:

> The exact behaviour then will be rather complicated. In general, (the
>   phonon mode) $\nu_q$ bends over, as in the linear case, but not
>   necessarily to a horizontal tangent.

[image]

This reminds me of electronic band structure, I think the electron bands are always horizontal at the zone boundary as long as the system has inversion or time reversal symmetry (? please correct me if I am wrong). It looks like the following picture:

[image]

Why not the phonon modes have the same property?

Comment: There is no requirement that the electron DOS be horizontal at a zone boundary (and for a free-electron like model definitely is not). Given that, why should there be a requirement on the phonons?

Comment: @JonCuster 1. not electron DOS 2. I am talking about crystals, not free electron gas

Comment: The free electron model for solids is the starting point for learning band structure in metals, many of which are free-electron like. So, again, nowhere in band structure theory and practice will you find a requirement for the band being horizontal at a symmetry point.

Comment: @JonCuster Let's confine the discussion of a single electron in a periodic potential, which has a length scale of $a$ and a finite size brillouin zone.

Comment: Cool. Make it a free, non-interacting electron in a periodic potential. Now throw in zone folding. Note that the band structure is not flat at the zone boundaries. Done.

Comment: Even for the weakest interaction, the infinite number of reflections in an infinite crystal should give rise to a standing wave, as I understand it. That is the nearly-free electron model for electrons. Or for phonons a small difference in masses/force constants.